# Terraform refresh not refreshing aws_api_gateway_deployment deployment ID

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When using Terraform to deploy our AWS infra, if we use the AWS console to redeploy an API Gateway deployment, it creates a new deployment ID. Afterwards when running *terraform apply* again, Terraform lists *aws_api_gateway_stage.deployment_id* as an in-place update item. Running *terraform refresh* does not update the state. It continues to show this as a delta. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform computes the delta based on what it already has saved on the backend and what there is on AWS at the moment of application. You can use Terraform to apply changes to AWS, but not the other way around, i.e. you cannot change your AWS configuration and expect Terraform to pull the changes into its state.